# Which proxy is best in sencha touch 2 in my situation?

Tags: rest, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to build an native app with sencha touch2,
But I'm a little confused about  the sencha touch proxy
In my app I need to get remote server data, register new user, update data.
So which proxy is best suitable in my situation? Ajax , REST or JSONP?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, make sure that you understand well about `Ext.data.proxy.Rest` through its documentation details:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Rest

`Ext.data.proxy.Rest` is a child class of `Ext.data.proxy.Ajax` so it means that everything you made will actually be transformed into an `Ajax` request. If your server-side design follows REST pattern completely, it's ideal to use REST proxy. But if there's no URL pattern convention for your backend system, you should simply use Ajax. In fact, you can still use REST in this case but you have to overwrite `buildUrl` method which is not really productive over pure Ajax proxy.

`Ajax` and `JSONP` are basically different about same-domain or cross-domain policy. Ajax is for same-domain request, and JSONP for cross-domain.